# how to print only index of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I print the only index of a data frame?

### input

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

### output

```
Mazda RX4 
Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710  
Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout
Valiant
```

Comment: Check `row.names(df)` to get what you want as a vector. Or `data.frame(v = row.names(mtcars))` to get the same as a `data.frame` with one column.

Comment: you can make this answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use`row.names(df)` to get what you want as a vector.

Or `data.frame(v = row.names(mtcars))` to get the same as a data frame with one column.